# Angularjs promise chain when working with a paginated collection

Tags: angularjs, promise

I'm working with a REST api that provides a paginated response for GET requests, like so:

```
{count: 43103
previous: null
next: http://ecoengine.berkeley.edu/api/photos/?page=2
results: [json objects....]
}
```

I would like to create a service that loads all the data by following the `next` link till `next` becomes null. I'm stuck on how to chain promises in this scenario and would appreciate any help on how to proceed (angular/js newbie here). My plunker with where i've gotten so far is here  http://plnkr.co/edit/ySiQLvu9RNrKkQAoDmKh. You can see from the console messages that the code retrieves data from first 2 pages only. Thank you.

Comment: You will get better help if you include the code in your post and explain better what you've tried and what your obstacle is.

Comment: Will do that next time I ask a question. For now I will accept Chandermani's answer. Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I tried to do chaining of promises using recursion to solve this scenario. See my fiddle here

http://plnkr.co/edit/NPh6uQ2DgVuhVxUgHB6h?p=info

Basically recursion done on loadData can get paged data. This is the implementation

```
var loadData = function(url) {
      var deferred = $q.defer();

      function loadAll() {
        $http.get(url)
           .then(function(d) {
                debugger;
                console.log('private http.get().then()');
                console.log(d);
                aggregateData.value.push(d.data.results);
                if(d.data.next) {
                   url=d.data.next;
                   loadAll();
                }
                else {
                   deferred.resolve(aggregateData.value);
                }
           })
      }
      debugger;
      loadAll();
      return deferred.promise;

 };
```

I used the `aggregateData` array but you are free to use any array declared in the loadData function.