# Chaining promises in Restangular for a paginated response

Tags: angularjs, restangular

I'm working with a REST API that returns a paginated response like the foll:

```
{count: 43103
previous: null
next: http://ecoengine.berkeley.edu/api/photos/?format=json&page=2
results: [json objects....]
}
```

Currently I'm using $http to get the data and chaining the promises using recursion. How would I do the same using Restangular? Here's my code using $http:

```
.factory('holosData', ['$q', '$http', function($q, $http ) {
     var aggregateData = { isLoaded: false, value: [] };          
     return {
          loadData: function(url) {
            var deferred = $q.defer();
            //empyt array of any previous results
            aggregateData.value.length = 0;
            function loadAll() {
              $http.get(url)
                 .then(function(d) {
                      aggregateData.value = aggregateData.value.concat(d.data.results);
                      if(d.data.next) {
                         url=d.data.next;
                         loadAll();
                      }
                      else {
                         deferred.resolve(aggregateData.value);
                      }
                 });
            }
            loadAll();
            return deferred.promise;
          },
          getData: function() {
               return aggregateData.value;
          }
}])
```

And here's what I've tried so far. I can fetch the first page, but I can't figure out how to chain promises in Restangular.

```
loadData: function() {
            var deferred = $q.defer();
            //empty array of any previous results
            allPhotos.length = 0;
            function loadAll() {
              Restangular.all('photos').getList(queryParams).then(function(list) {
                allPhotos = list;
                deferred.resolve(allPhotos);
              });
            }
            loadAll();
            return deferred.promise;
}
```

Thanks!

Comment: Perhaps this question helps to you: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20171928/angularjs-promise-chain-when-working-with-a-paginated-collection